# Why can't Hotmail (or other providers) tell the difference between spoof and real emails?

Tags: email, outlook.com, phishing

Why can't Hotmail tell the difference between spoof and real emails from a domain (such as blizzard.com)? I get swamped with phishing emails from "blizzard.com" so I put it on my blacklist but then I can't get legitimate emails.

Is there no information in the headers that can be used to definitively determine where the email came from?

Comment: This probably shouldn't have been migrated, but now it has two answers here it's not feasible to cancel the migration and I don't want to remigrate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- SMTP is designed to allow any host relay messages originally sent by another host. For example, I could run a SMTP server for my own domain, but configure server B to accept mail whenever my server is down and forward it later to its destination.
- Every hop, including the sender (whether legitimate or not), can add any header they wish; for example, a secretary can put the boss' address in `From`. And so can a spammer. It's not uncommon to see spam with spoofed `Received` or `Date` headers too.
- [SPF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sender_Policy_Framework) was created to allow a domain's owner to specify which servers are allowed to send messages claiming to be from that domain. `blizzard.com` has a SPF record, but either Hotmail does not check it at all or ignores the "reject" rule. Or the fake mail is being sent from an *allowed* host.
- Some mail servers (especially the big ones, such as Gmail or Yahoo! Mail) attach a [DKIM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DomainKeys_Identified_Mail) digital signature to all outgoing messages. However, while this can prove that a message is *legitimate*, it does absolutely nothing to detect *fake* messages, because the recipient just does not know whether DKIM was disabled intentionally or not.

  - When DNSSEC becomes widespread enough, it might be possible to check if the sender has published a DKIM key; however, this would cause other problems.
- There exist ways to digitally sign single messages – [PGP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pretty_Good_Privacy) and [S/MIME](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S/MIME) – but they, like DKIM, are equally useless against spam.

Answer (score 1):

Problem is that any information which the official Blizzard could put in the headers, the "spoofers" could also put in their headers.

Comment: -1 not true: it is practically impossible for "spoofers" to sign a message with DKIM or similar message authentication signature.

Comment: @David: This only works if signatures are _required_ by the receiving system. In reality, most just assume that the sender is not DKIM-capable in the first place.